# Как можно показать градиент при наведении?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как можно показать градиент внутри фигуры при наведении на нее?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `div:hover { background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(85,85,170,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%); }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
div:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 25%, black 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

А вот так?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, red), color-stop(33%, red), color-stop(66%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background-size: 1px 300vh;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

div:hover {
  background-position: -200vh;
}
```

```html
<div>наведи</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

если под фигурой вы имели в виду `div` , то `:hover` и `linear-gradient` в помощь

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

div:hover {
   background: linear-gradient(to top, red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```